# How to use a Pandas column inside a regex in .str.extract() function

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe with two columns. I need to use the content of first column to search at second column and capture some content based on regex.

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | word1/word2/key1 |
| key2 | word3/word4/word5/key2 |
| key3 | word6/key3/word7 |

I need to search "key1" in word1/word2/key1 and capture the string between the two "/" before "key1". In this example, on the first row, i need to capture "word2", on the second row, i need to capture "word5" and on the third row i need to capture word6.
I don't know how to pass "column1" as a variable inside regex in .str.extract(r'/(\w{1,})/"column1"').

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can use `.apply( func, axis=1 )` to have a function called with each row, one by one.  You can return a value and have it stored in a new column.

Answer (score 1):

Building off Tim Roberts' comment, you can write a function that acts on a row of your data frame. I suggest avoiding the use of a regular expression if you can. Assuming that there are always words delimited by a forward slash (`/`) in column 2, then you could do something like this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1": ["key1", "key2"],
    "column2": ["word/word2/key1", "word3/word4/key2"]
})

def extract_preceding_word(row):
    query, string = row
    parts = string.split("/")
    idx = parts.index(query)
    return parts[idx - 1]

new_df = df.assign(
    new_column2=lambda DF: DF.apply(extract_middle_word, axis=1)
)

print(new_df)
```

The result is

```
  column1           column2 new_column2
0    key1   word/word2/key1       word2
1    key2  word3/word4/key2       word4
```

A few things to point out here.

1. If the first column might contain characters that have special meaning for a regular expression, you will need to take care to escape those when generating the regex.

   - For example, could column1 have a value like `key1(foo)` ?
2. I would suggest avoiding having the data in a `pandas.DataFrame`, if you can. This problem might be easier to solve with two lists instead of two columns.

If you really need a regular expression, I recommend using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to develop your pattern. To get you started, a [lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#index-20) may be what you need. For example

```py
def extract_preceding_word_regex(row):
    query, string = row
    pat = rf"([^/]+)(?=/{query})"
    out = re.sub(pat, r"\1", string)
    return out
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Roberts and @ogdenkev! My first example was too simple. The key from column1 can be at any position on column2. I edited my sample dataframe on the question. I tried to edit the regex "pat" to fit my objective, but i wasn't able.

Comment: I added ways to handle the situations you described.